# Android Webview - Prevent Reload When Go Back to the App

Tags: android-webview

How to prevent reload on webview when your back to the app? When tapping home key and then back to the app, the webview was reloaded. I dont want this behaviour, I want users to view the previous page (w/o reload) that they accessed.

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl( WEBSITE_URL );
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Test this by adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to your `<activity>` element in your `androidmanifest.xml`.

Comment: I actually went with "singleTop" instead of "singleInstance".  It appears that this is the preferred way to do it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Is this working if you tap the system's back button? Home button if pressed is working but not with back button. Is this possible with back button? Its not working on me.