# Android-WebView reloads when device wakes up

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm having this issue where the webview reloads everytimes the device wakes up from sleep, Or when the app is reopen from the task switcher. I'm positive that the activity is not destroyed but the webView reloads. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to your `<activity>` element in your `androidmanifest.xml` (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15782542/7908996).

This solved the problem for me.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/22412313/7908996. Cheers.